# How to mass edit an .sql dump file with MySQL Workbench in Windows?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an .sql dump file that was exported from a database server (AWS) using HEIDISQL. Typical of dump files, this file just contains all of the .SQL codes and data required to reconstruct all tables and schemas etc., in total 8MB in file size.

I want to mass edit some columns in a few tables (for example replace all values with blanks). I thought Workbench could do this.

So I fired up Workbench 8.0, loaded the .sql file via Ctrl+Shift+O. The software took some time to read 8MB of data and eventually showed the .SQL code in its editor. Now I don't know how to go from this to actual data tables the way that Workbench would load data from a data server.

I thought the most obvious way is to execute the entire file, but the execute (lightning buttons) are grayed out, along with almost all of the buttons on that row (see photo).

[image: screenshot]

So how can I load the tables so that I can begin editing the rows?

If it is not possible with Workbench, do you know which apps out there could do it for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

For text operations, *MySQL Workbench* isn't the tool.

I would recommend using *Notepad++* or any other text editor with advanced find and replace options.

Once your *SQL* is fixed, you can take it back to *MySQL Workbench* for execution.

Answer (score 1):

When the execution button is greyed out it means you have no active connection to a MySQL server. Thus you should open one from the home screen and then open the sql file.

However, instead of loading the SQL and editing in tables you could use search + replace in the SQL editor. It supports regular expressions, which should give you what's needed even for complex searches.